# Deletion of rows with foreign key constraints

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on a requirement.

There is one table.I want to delete a row from this table but i cannot delete it because

1.This table is referred by 79 table through foreign key relationship 
2.Each of those 79 tables are referred by other 100's of table

so you can imagine its kind of tree structure.So i need to start from bottom and reach to TOP.I need to do it through SQL

So from where I should start ???Do i need to create a temp table or anything which i can do any approach which can be useful???

Note:CASCADE DELETE NOT ALLOWED

I might not have access to any sys tables.. any approach that can be handy??? I am using oracle 10g

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowed"?

Comment: means the tables are designed in such a way that cascade delete cannot be done

Answer (score 3):

See: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/disable.php

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
disable CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Just be sure to understand the consequences of doing such a procedure and the effects it will have on other data / application functions.

Also, if it wasn't obvious be sure to enable the constraint afterwards

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
enable CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Comment: see we can't disable the contraint because application and database structure might be effected

Comment: and we dont have access to sys table I cannot find the constraint name

Comment: Then I'd guess the problem is outside my scope of knowledge. The only other solution I'd give is to delete references to the row starting from an unconstrained table going toward the table in question, but as you stated that is not realistic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following query (that does not need access to sys tables) to get all the Foreign Keys of a table and their corresponding Primary Keys. You could use this to build some kind of recursive function that goes through your tree and deletes all parent entries.

```
select uc.constraint_name, ucc.table_name, ucc.column_name from
user_constraints uc
left join user_cons_columns ucc on (uc.r_constraint_name = ucc.constraint_name)
where uc.table_name = 'TABLENAME'
and uc.constraint_type = 'R'
```

Comment: user_constraints is defined under sys in our DB so i cannot access...any other approach can you suggest

Comment: Hard to believe you can't even access `user_constraints`. However if you really can't, I don't see any solution for you either, sorry.

Comment: can we create a table and hard code the values or any other approach hich you can suggest

Comment: If you can get a one-time-access to the user_constraints table, you could use `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` to create a copy of the constraints-list and use this as a base for a recursive deletion function.

Comment: ok once we get the access...what will the recursive query looks like

Comment: I didn't mean a recursive query. You could use a recursive pl/sql function. (1) You want to delete a row in your table (2) use your function to look up all foreign keys references of the table in question (3) delete the row in the foreign key table of the foreign key reference in question (4) until you arrive at a table that has no more foreign key references, go to (2)

Comment: what if we hard code all the dependencies in a temp table or flat file and read  from there

Comment: Using `CTAS` on the query above is basically the same, a hard copy of all the foreign key references in your database (if you remove the where clause of course).

Comment: `user_constraints` is always defined under sys, but it is selectable by `PUBLIC` and there is always a public synonym for it. Every single user can see their own tables and the constraints on them.

Comment: can sysadmin diable access to user_constraint

Comment: can, yes, but must not, never, ever! `user_constraints` belongs to `SYS` and is part of the data dictionary. To quote the [concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datadict.htm#CNCPT1211) guide "No Oracle Database user should _ever_ alter rows or schema objects contained in the SYS schema because such activity can compromise data integrity"