# How to delete rows within the table when there are foreign keys in other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

Here is my tables: (I am using Oracle SQL)

```
FILM (Catalog_Num, Format, Title, Year, Number_Discs, Rating, Timing, Genre)
INVENTORY (Film_ID, Rental_Price, New, Date_In, Catalog_Num@, Store_Num@)
```

Now I want to delete the rows that the year of the film over 2015,
so I wrote:

```
delete from film 
where catalog_num in(
select catalog_num
from film join inventory using (catalog_num)
where year >'2015';
```

However, it shows the error that integrity constraint violated-child record found

How can I fix the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Delete the rows in other tables that are dependent on those keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deletion of rows with foreign key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261926/deletion-of-rows-with-foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: The best way to do this is to use the CASCADE DELETE functionality. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan - only for certain values of "best". For many people a major benefit of foreign keys is that they prevent us from accidentally deleting rows which have dependent records.

Comment: @APC, I completely agree. `CASCADE DELETE` is best suited only in parent-child relationship where child has no existence without parent.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with the record in your `inventory` table.

you can for example modify your constraint and add `on delete cascade`, so the record will be deleted with the other record.

```
CONSTRAINT fk_column
     FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
```

or you set `on delete set null` so the fk will be set to `null`

```
CONSTRAINT fk_column
     FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Comment: Can I use a SQL statement to finish the query instead of changing the table constraint?

Comment: yes, you should first delete records from table with a fk and than you will be able to delete from the parent table.

Comment: @ShinYuWu - you asked for a single SQL statement. Altering the foreign keys to cascade on delete is the way to fulfil your requirement in a single statement. The alternative is separate preliminary deletes from the child tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to delete the referenced records :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DISABLE CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Comment: this is not a good solution in my opinion, because 1) it remains data that you no longer need.
2) information for the optimizer is missing, which can possibly lead to worse queries

Comment: Of course it's not a good solution.. cascade is better which you already answered..it's his call..

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a record which is referenced by some other record, you must also do something with the latter one: either delete the record or the reference. You can do it manually with another delete statement, but probably it'd be better to entrust this task to Oracle.

If you want to delete the record, provide a constraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.
If you just want to remove the reference, provide `ON DELETE SET NULL` option.

You can read more about it here: [Data Integrity](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/datainte.htm#CNCPT021)